# Use JQuery to select and change the remaining elements with the same class

Tags: jquery

I have multiple divs containing the same class, after someone clicks on one of the divs, I want to perform two actions -

Add class "ABC" to the div that was clicked
Add class "DEF" to all the other divs containing the same class
Example -

```
<div class="ZZZ"></div>
<div class="YYY"></div>
<div class="YYY"></div>
<div class="YYY"></div>
<div class="ZZZ"></div>
```

If someone clicks the 2nd div, the results should look like this -

```
<div class="ZZZ"></div>       
<div class="YYY ABC"></div>   <--clicked
<div class="YYY DEF"></div>   
<div class="YYY DEF"></div>
<div class="ZZZ"></div>
```

How can this be accomplished with JQuery?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this untested code:

```
$('div').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // Find current class of clicked div, remove classes ABC and DEF,
    // store it in currentClass variable
    var currentClass = $(this).attr('class').replace('ABC', '').replace('DEF', '').trim();
    // remove classes ABC and DEF from all other divs:
    $('div').removeClass('ABC').removeClass('DEF');
    // add class DEF for all divs with selected current class
    $('.' + currentClass ).addClass('DEF');
    // for selected element remove class DEF and add class ABC
    $(this).removeClass('DEF').addClass('ABC');
});
```

Comment: This is the one I used though I imagine some of the others will work too. Thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this,

```
$('div').click(function() {
    $('div').removeClass('ABC').removeClass('DEF');

    var selection = $(this).attr('class');

    $(this).addClass('ABC');
    $(this).siblings('.' + selection).addClass('DEF');
});
```

See the example: https://jsfiddle.net/otps7sfa/

Answer (score 0):

How about this (completely untested)?

```
$('.YYY').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.YYY').removeClass('ABC').addClass('DEF');
    $(this).addClass('ABC');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to  give a common attribute to all div. i.e.

```
<div class="rrr ZZZ"></div>
<div class="rrr YYY"></div>
<div class="rrr YYY"></div>
<div class="rrr YYY"></div>
<div class="rrr ZZZ"></div>
```

i gave class 'rrr' to ALL divs. now let we write jquery

```
$('.rrr').click(function (e) {
    var classn = $(this).attr('class').replace('rrr ', '');
    $('.' + classn).addClass('DEF');
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).removeClass('DEF').addClass('ABC');
});
```

I hope you understand the flow. and it help you

Comment: yes my brother, just solved that. i forget to keep a ")" before addclass

Comment: Thank you so much for siddel... this is giving output and no error ....